# How can I have a 1:many table but a 1:1 navigation property?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have two entities; let's call them Person and Address. A Person has only one current address [*insert joke about political candidate here*], but also has previous addresses, which are also stored in the Address table. Thus I want my database tables to have a 1:many relationship.

*However*, in my entity classes, I don't want a 1:many relationship between Person and Address, because I'm only really interested in their *current* address. (If I want to find out about their previous addresses, then I can look directly at the Address table). So, I do *not* want a 1:many "Addresses" property on the Person object. Instead, I want a 1:1 Address property, which I'll set to the current address.

Can this be done?

Comment: Wouldn't the most natural thing be to store the previous addresses in a separate table, e.g. AddressHistory? Is it really important that they're in the same table?

Comment: It's a complex table, and I don't want to have to duplicate the structure (and attendant logic). I don't believe my table design should be driven by the tools, so I'd prefer to structure my tables as I would if I were creating them directly. (I wish I'd used DB first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can't be done. Navigation properties represent foreign key relationships and the FK relationship in your database represents *many* addresses for *one* person. The current address is the result of a specific query in your database, for example - depending on how "*current*" defined - a "select top(1) ... order by addresscreationdate descending" query on all addresses of a given person.

Possible solutions in my opinion are:

- Either create a second relationship with a foreign key `CurrentAddressId` in the person table refering to the current address. Then you could have a navigation reference `CurrentAddress` in your `Person` class.
- Or perform the query to load the current address in a repository or service class with a `GetCurrentAddress(Person person)` method or similar. But you can't have a navigation property for the current address on the `Person` class then.

Comment: Thanks. I've gone with your first solution. So I have both an Addresses and a CurrentAddress relationship.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do this through mapping because EF relations tightly follows DB relations. Moreover one-to-one relation in EF is based on placing foreign key on primary key in dependent table (address and person would need to have exactly same primary key value) and this requirement would not work with your expectation to have old addresses in the table as well.

I would try this approach (not tested):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext {

    public MyContext() {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += 
            (sender, e) => {
                var person = e.Person as Person;
                if (person != null) {
                    // Fill the property manually
                    person.Address = this.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(/* some condition */);
                }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder) {
        // Do not map the propery
        builder.Entity<Person>().Ignore(p => p.Address);

        // other mapping
    }

    public override int SaveChanges() {

        // TODO: here you must have your own change tracking logic
        // for address to know when the address has changed and 
        // new record must be created in the database for old address

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    // rest of context class
}
```

Comment: Thanks +1. Your solution is very impressive, but too "scary" for me. I'll just have to accept that I have a 1:many property *and* a 1:1 property as Slauma suggests.

Comment: @GaryMcGill: Even if you don't use it and it is "too scary" this is the correct answer to your question "Can it be done and how?" and you should accept Ladislav's answer rather than mine.

Comment: @Slauma: Right answer for OP does not necessary be the answer solving the problem. My answer is mostly workaround to missing feature and it brings some disadvantages like manual change tracking for address and also N+1 query issue if you try to load N persons.